# spark python in zeppelin aws error running program

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I had try example code about python in zeppelin web service spark aws emr and  found error when running this code
the output i expected is wordcount in afile in my s3 storage

```
text_file = sc.textFile("s3://mybuckettest2/Scenarios.txt")
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
counts.saveAsTextFile("s3://mybuckettest2/test.txt")
```

The error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-2374039163027007666.py", line 319, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-2374039163027007666.py", line 307, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

Comment: sc is not defined.

Comment: i had try this code on aws  emr hue web service. this code run successfully

Answer (score 0):

I found this from the [documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html).

> SparkContext, SQLContext and ZeppelinContext are automatically created and exposed as variable names sc, sqlContext and z, respectively, in Scala, Python and R environments. Staring from 0.6.1 SparkSession is available as variable spark when you are using Spark 2.x.

It means that the `sc` is for scala and you have to use `sqlContext` for pyspark.

Comment: i think this is because zeppelin doesn't have sc dependencies, but hue has sc dependencies